# NGRX bulk effect of already defined single effect

Tags: ngrx

So, Im working on an app with a concept of "Plans" and each plan you can add a comment. That part works fine, but it seems to fail and get confused if i try to run this in a loop.

**The Action:**

```
export class AddComment implements Action {
  readonly type = CommentActionTypes.AddComment;

  constructor(public payload: Comment) {}
}

export class AddCommentSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = CommentActionTypes.AddCommentSuccess;

  constructor(public payload: Comment) {}
}
```

**Effect**

```
  @Effect()
  addComment$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType<AddComment>(CommentActionTypes.AddComment).pipe(
    switchMap(action => this.commentService.addComment(this.disciplineType, action.payload)),
    map((comment: any) => new AddCommentSuccess(comment)),
    catchError(err => of(new AddCommentFail(err)))
  );
```

**Implementation**

What im struggling with is firing this off in rapid success/ I have a situation where I want to add a duplicate comment to multiple plans.

```
saveSet.forEach(x => {
          comment.plan_id = x.id;
          this.store.dispatch(this.buildAddCommentAction(comment));
        });
```

For reference:

```
buildAddCommentAction(comment: DisciplineComment) : Action {
  return new CommentActions.AddComment(comment);
}
```

**What is Happening**

If i have a list of 5 plans, and want to add a duplicate comment to all of them, Im only getting a successful response for the last item in the loop.

Now i know that is overly chatty, that is 5 separate client/service calls. What I cant figure out, its what the prescribed approach to this should be?

1.) A new BulkAddComment Action, effect, etc. Im loathe to do this becuase I have Comments, Concerns (similar in function and need), and one of each for every "discipline". Thatd be about 36 new effects and twice that in actions. A serious refactor is needed.

2.) Modify the actions and effects for 1 or multiple

3.)?

Thanks for input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using the `switchMap` operator which will cancel the current running observable, in your case the service call.

You'll have to use `concatMap` or `mergeMap`. If the order is important use `concatMap`, if not use `mergeMap` because this will make your service calls in parallel.

For more info, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dsku0F4lU3A).

Comment: This worked. Any side effects I should be worried about or aware of?

Comment: No, not really.